# iPhone X : : Error : safe-area-inset property is not supported for this property?

Tags: ios, ios11, iphone-x, ios11.2

For aligning html page on an iPhoneX, apple had provided the constants like constant(safe-area-inset-left),etc.
This was working fine, last I checked in iOS 11.0.x. After updating to iOS 11.2, it has stopped working. I'm getting this error/warning in css "The value constant(safe-area-inset-left) is not supported by this property."

```
padding-left: constant(safe-area-inset-left) !important;
```

Viewport is also not working.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 11.2 constant(safe-area-inset-dir) is replaced by env(safe-area-inset-dir)

Comment: Is there any official statement from Apple regarding these changes?

Comment: @PrateekPande I can not find a statement from Apple, but here is the official documentation of Webkit: https://webkit.org/blog/7929/designing-websites-for-iphone-x/